# c# sql server dependency

Tags: c#, ado.net, dependencies

I used dependency in small project. I want that if my database data change, i

understand it and update the text of two buttons. (my buttons text show an integer number that store in DB)

So here is my code :

```
var connectionString =
"data source=(local);initial catalog=batis;integrated security=False; User ID=sa;Password=123"; ;
_tblDependencyFacture = new SqlTableDependency<Sepand.POS.Sales.Model.Facture>(connectionString, "Facture");
_tblDependencyFacture.OnChanged += TableDependency_OnChanged;
_tblDependencyFacture.OnError += TableDependency_OnError;
_tblDependencyFacture.Start();
```

And here is my Onchange method:

```
private void TableDependency_OnChanged(object sender, TableDependency.EventArgs.RecordChangedEventArgs<Model.Facture> e)
{
    if (e.Entity.Id == currentFactureRow.FACTURE_ID)
    {
        if (e.Entity.FacturePrintCount != currentFactureRow.FACTURE_LAST_PRINT_NO_IN ||
                  e.Entity.OrderPrintCount != currentFactureRow.FACTURE_ORDER_PRINT_NO_IN)
        {
             showPrintCounts(e.Entity.FacturePrintCount ?? default(int), e.Entity.OrderPrintCount ?? default(int));
             buttonPrintFacture.Refresh();
             buttonPrintOrder.Refresh();
         }
    }
}
```

in showPrintCounts method i update the text of my buttons. And then i refresh

them to redraw themselves.But my problem is that after showPrintCounts method

terminate,

```
buttonPrintFacture.Refresh()
```

and

```
buttonPrintOrder.Refresh()
```

never execute. I track my code by break point. after showPrintCounts

terminates, the whole `TableDependency_OnChanged()` methode terminate and

button refresh never executed. i also put

```
buttonPrintFacture.Refresh();
buttonPrintOrder.Refresh();
```

in `showPrintCounts()` method but still did not work.

Comment: It looks like that showPrintCounts throws exception otherwise you should get to two line below. Could you check for exception thrown and provide body of showPrintCounts?

Comment: thanks you are right i use try catch and i got cross thread operation not valid error.i should check it...